# How should I configure Vulkan for cider-jack-in?

Tags: emacs, clojure, environment-variables, vulkan, cider

I'm working through the newly released [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/) in [Clojure](https://clojure.org/) with [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), and I've hit a bit of a snag. The example [makefile project](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_Setting_up_a_makefile_project) works perfectly, but I'm having trouble translating it into Clojure.

My [`build.boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Configuring-Boot#configuring-your-clojure-project) file just specifies the [`:source-paths`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-Environment#env-keys) and adds [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) as a dependency:

```clj
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src"}
 :dependencies
 (let [lwjgl-version "3.0.0"]
   [['org.lwjgl/lwjgl lwjgl-version]
    ['org.lwjgl/lwjgl-platform lwjgl-version :classifier "natives-linux"]]))
```

Then, in `src/example/core.clj`, I have an `extension-count` function that uses [`vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties.html) as demonstrated in the original example:

```clj
(ns example.core
  (:import (org.lwjgl.vulkan VK10)))

(defn extension-count []
  (let [^String layer-name nil
        property-count (int-array 1)]
    (VK10/vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties layer-name property-count nil)
    (first property-count)))
```

Now, from Bash, I can set the relevant environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `VK_LAYER_PATH` as I start up a REPL:

```
$ VULKAN_SDK_PATH=~/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK_PATH/lib VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK_PATH/etc/explicit_layer.d boot repl
boot.user=> (require '[example.core :refer [extension-count]])
nil
boot.user=> (extension-count)
4
```

As you can see, everything works correctly. But of course, when I use [`cider-jack-in`](http://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/up_and_running/#launch-an-nrepl-server-and-client-from-emacs) by <kbd>C-c M-j</kbd> instead, I get an [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) because CIDER isn't setting those variables:

```
boot.user> (import (java.util.function Consumer)
                   (org.lwjgl.system Configuration))
org.lwjgl.system.Configuration
boot.user> (Configuration/setDebugStreamConsumer
            (reify Consumer
              (accept [_ message]
                (println message))))
nil
boot.user> (require '[example.core :refer [extension-count]])
nil
boot.user> (extension-count)
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
    b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: libvulkan.so.1
```

Am I supposed to be setting `java.library.path` or `org.lwjgl.librarypath`, as suggested in the above error message, instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I can set either of those variables from [`profile.boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Configuring-Boot#configuring-your-clojure-project):

```clj
(System/setProperty
 "java.library.path"
 (str (System/getProperty "user.home") "/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/lib"))
```

Now when I try <kbd>C-c M-j</kbd> again, it works:

```
boot.user> (require '[example.core :refer [extension-count]])
nil
boot.user> (extension-count)
4
```

However, this still doesn't let me set `VK_LAYER_PATH`, which will be fairly important in the future:

> We will start using validation layers in Vulkan and you need to tell the Vulkan library where to load these from using the `VK_LAYER_PATH` variable:
>
> ```
> test: VulkanTest
>     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(VULKAN_SDK_PATH)/lib VK_LAYER_PATH=$(VULKAN_SDK_PATH)/etc/explicit_layer.d ./VulkanTest
> ```

How can I set these environment variables for `cider-jack-in`? I'd prefer not to have to manually configure CIDER's dependencies for a [standalone repl](http://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/#setting-up-a-standalone-repl) in a separate terminal and then connect to it using [`cider-connect`](http://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/up_and_running/#connect-to-a-running-nrepl-server), but if there's no other option here, I guess that's what I'll have to do.